# How to get around HTTP Error 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, restlet

I'm using Restet and I wanted to know if its possible if a ServerResource entity type is set, for example for this type of entity:

```
@XStreamAlias("role")
@ApiModel
public class Role {

    private String entityId;
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = "")
    private List<String> aclRead;
    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = "")
    private List<String> acLWrite;
    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = "")
    private Boolean publicRead;
    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = "")
    private Boolean publicWrite;

    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getAclRead() {
        return aclRead;
    }

    public void setAclRead(List<String> aclRead) {
        this.aclRead = aclRead;
    }

    public List<String> getAcLWrite() {
        return acLWrite;
    }

    public void setAcLWrite(List<String> acLWrite) {
        this.acLWrite = acLWrite;
    }

    public Boolean getPublicRead() {
        return publicRead;
    }

    public void setPublicRead(Boolean publicRead) {
        this.publicRead = publicRead;
    }

    public Boolean getPublicWrite() {
        return publicWrite;
    }

    public void setPublicWrite(Boolean publicWrite) {
        this.publicWrite = publicWrite;
    }

}
```

How can we be able to POST without the need of passing all the fields, for this example we only wanted to pass the "name" from the Client Request, but doing that throws `415 - Unsupported Media Type`

In our client we only do pass this JSON

```
{
  "role" : {
     "name" : "AdminRole" 
  }
}
```

For the Get response of the Resource, the return type is Role also so the client will get all the fields, entityId, name, aclRead, aclWrite, publicRead and publicWrite through the Restlet marshalling.

The problem we have is that we cannot POST.

Comment: 415 is for Unsupported Media Type not for Unprocessable Entity.

Answer (score 0):

In the post request, the json data should only consist of the the entity parameters without the entity name as root key. So, your post request should look like this:

```
{
    "name" : "AdminRole" 
}
```